# GAE PHP user prefix subdomain

Tags: php, google-app-engine, mod-rewrite, wildcard-subdomain

I have this URL for each users on my site: `http://appsite.com/dennis`, I was able to get this done using a mod_rewrite routing found on appengine docs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/mod_rewrite.

However I am looking to change it to something like `http://dennis.appsite.com` as this is more SEO efficient. I am unsure where to start from any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've been doing research for hours now and I only found a lot of solution for Apache and not on appengine

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a custom domain, but not on appspot.com.

Refer to the documentation on [wildcard subdomain mapping](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain#more_about_wildcard_subdomain_mapping) on what's possible.

Once the request gets to your app you use the modify the mod_rewrite example you linked to to pull out the right path from the REQUEST_URI.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried your solution but `$path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);` only gives me the string after the domain.

Comment: You might also need to pull in routing information from SERVER_NAME and HTTP_HOST as well, depending on how you configure your wildcard.